# JQuery DataTable with Fixed Column Width

Tags: jquery, datatable, fixed-width, dynamic-columns

I am dynamically creating a HTML table. Number of rows and columns are not fixed. I am using JQuery datatable to extend my html table.Problem is width of the columns, it always take the auto width (I guess dividing the sScrollX width among the number of columns). How can I set the width of my columns? CSS has no effect on column width.

As seen in the image below columns are wider than expected

[image]

Comment: Do the cols have a class?

Comment: I see the columns go off the page, do you have width 100% on the table and do the current td have a fixed width on them?

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/HKW43/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>   
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    winW = $(window).width();       
    firstRow = $('table tr:eq(0) td').length;
    $('table tr td').css({width:winW/firstRow+'px'});
});
```

Example => http://jsfiddle.net/HKW43/

For update width on window resize see => http://jsfiddle.net/HKW43/2/

Comment: Are you sure about "height"??

Comment: Please see the attached image.Hope this helps